add texonomy to wordpress post with javascript
I’ve developed a plugin that adds a button to the edit.php page in the WordPress admin. This button populates certain fields with data from a remote JSON file. However, I’m having trouble adding the title and taxonomy data correctly. Could someone please help me figure out how to do this?
Here is my code:
    <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.getElementById('loadButton').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var imdbID = document.getElementById('imdb-title').value;
            var url = '/wp-content/plugins/imdb/get.php?id=' + imdbID;

            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    //document.getElementById('name').value = data.name || '';
                    document.getElementById('ratings-movie').value = data.score || '';
                    document.getElementById('year-type').value = data.year || '';
                    document.getElementById('period-time').value = data.duration || '';
                    document.getElementById('rating').value = data.vote || '';
                    document.getElementById('gross-worldwide-movie').value = data.boxoffice || '';  
                    document.getElementById('age-limit').value = data.contentrating || '';
                    document.getElementById('awards-series').value = data.awards || '';
                    document.getElementById('metascore').value = data.metascore  || ''; 
                    document.getElementById('top250-movies').value = data.imdbrate   || '';
                    document.getElementById('budget-movie').value = data.budget  || '';
                    //document.getElementById('title').value = data.name;
                    var tags = '1,2,3,4,5,56,7';
                    //var tags = data.tags || '';  
                    var tagInput = document.getElementById('components-form-token-input-0'); 
                    if (tags && tagInput) {
                    tags.split(',').forEach(function(tag) {
                        tag = tag.trim();
                        if (tag) {

                            tagInput.value = tag;

                            document.getElementById('submit_tag').click();
                        }
                    });
                    }
            })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
                    alert('Error loading JSON data.');
                });
        });
    });
    </script>

the title and tags (taxonomy) fields are not being filled as expected. All other fields are populated correctly, but the title remains empty, and the tags are not assigned

I don't see anything in your code which refers to "title" or "taxonomy". Which part of your code are you expecting will process that information? And what happens when you run that code, exactly? You say you're "having trouble" but that doesn't indicate what actual problem is occurring. Is there an error? Unexpected output? Something else? It's unclear. Have a look at [ask], and remember we can't see your screen or run your code. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

@ADyson see line 24-37 for tags and line 23 for title. i comment this line because its not work. wordpress tag box not work with this code and i cant fine any solution in google or Ai .

line 24-37 for tags...you said the problem was about "taxonomy". Is that the same thing as "tags"? Please use terminology consistently, then people know what you mean, or at least point it out in your post if it won't be obvious. You can [edit] your post, by the way

"its not work"...we have no idea what this means in practice. We can't fix "not work". Can your mechanic fix your car when you tell him "its not work"...or does he ask for extra information?? Again consider that we can't see your screen or run your code. As I mentioned before, what happens when you run this? Is there an error? An unexpected output? Or what? Consider also that this code is supposed to update some HTML but you haven't shown us the HTML, and we also don't know what's in data when you're testing this, so we can't even predict what it might do. Please provide a proper [mre]

We'd like to help you, but if you post a question which is vague, unclear, and incomplete, which is how it is right now, then nobody will be able to give you any meaningful assistance. Think carefully and review your post in detail, and then update it. Looking forward to seeing some code, data and debugging information which we can use to diagnose your specific problem. Thanks.

The only thing I would comment, from the code provided, is regarding the tag code: if (tag) { tagInput.value = tag; ...because this is in a loop, it will keep overwriting the tag field with the latest value of tag, every time you loop. So you'll possibly only see the last value from the tags in the field. Is that what you're seeing? Or is there a different problem? It's unclear what document.getElementById('submit_tag').click(); would cause to happen, since we know nothing about that button, or any code triggered by clicking it.

It's hard to tell precisely what the problem is without also seeing the HTML for this as well, however a few things stand out:

The title and name fields use the IDs "title" and "name" which are quite generic and I would not at all be surprised if there is also something else on the page with the same ID. If that's the case when you use document.getElementById() it will only ever find the first element with that ID.
With regards to the tags, you're clicking a button in a tight loop (i.e. you're not waiting for a result before continuing), depending on the mechanism behind that tag submission, you may see unexpected behaviour. If it submits to the server it may be better to wait for the reponse to come back before attempting to submit the next tag, if it adds it to the UI and stores it locally before submitting, you may want to verify that the item was added in the UI where you expect to see it. I think regardless of which method is happening, using a "waitFor" type method to wait for the item to be present in the UI is probably a good approach (assuming that if it gets sent to the server it is added to the UI after a successful request).

